# How to modify timesyncd.conf in a yocto recipe

Tags: linux, configuration, embedded, yocto, bitbake

I have a yocto build and now I am trying to write a recipe in which I can adjust the parameters in the configuration file under `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`.

Responsible for the file is probably the recipe under `/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_250.5.bb`
There I can find the following lines of code:

```
CONFFILES:${PN} = "\
...
    ${sysconfdir}/systemd/timesyncd.conf \
...
"
```

The problem here is, that I couldn't find any references to this except for the few lines I just showed you.

If I write an own recipe which puts its own `timesyncd.conf` file in this place, the result is that the `.conf`-file of the systemd recipe ends up on the final image with the following name: `timesyncd.conf-opkg`
Usually I use `.bbappend`-files to "overwrite" files of other recipes. Because it seems to me right now, that the original `timesyncd.conf` files is made out of thin air I could not do the same.

So I wanted to ask if the file really comes from this package and if so, are there best practices to "reconfigure" configuration files from standard packages like this.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Without changing the main configuration file (as you are trying to do now but fails for some reason), try drop-in configuration snippets as mentioned in [https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timesyncd.conf.html](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timesyncd.conf.html). Drop-ins have a higher precedence and override the main configuration file settings.